# How can I add a swipe gesture to my side menu controller?

Tags: swift

I made a side menu with some controls and I can dismiss it when the user taps outside of the side menu or if he/she selects a row inside the side menu. Now I want to add a swipe gesture to the left so that the user can dismiss it that way too.

---

```
extension MenuViewController {

@objc func dismissControllerAnimated() {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
} }

class SlideinTransition: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

let menuViewController = MenuViewController()

var isPresenting = true
let dimmingView = UIView()

func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
    return 0.5
}

func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    guard let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to),
    let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) else { return }
    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

    let finalWidth = toViewController.view.bounds.width * 0.3
    let finalHeight = toViewController.view.bounds.height

    if isPresenting{

        //adds a tap gesture to our dimming view
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: toViewController, action: #selector(MenuViewController.dismissControllerAnimated))
        dimmingView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        //adds the dimming view
        dimmingView.backgroundColor = .black
        dimmingView.alpha = 0.0
        containerView.addSubview(dimmingView)
        dimmingView.frame = containerView.bounds
        //adds the menu view controller to our container
        containerView.addSubview(toViewController.view)

        //init frame off the screen
        toViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: -finalWidth, y: 0, width: finalWidth, height: finalHeight)
    }

    let transform = {
        self.dimmingView.alpha = 0.5
        toViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: finalWidth, y: 0)
    }

    //applies a specific kind of transformation to our view
    let identity = {
        self.dimmingView.alpha = 0.0
        fromViewController.view.transform = .identity
    }

    //animates the transition and cancels it when you click outside of the frame
    let duration = transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)
    let isCancelled = transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
        self.isPresenting ? transform() : identity()
    }) { (_) in
        transitionContext.completeTransition(!isCancelled)
        if !self.isPresenting {
            self.dimmingView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

}

---

I instantiate my "MenuViewController" like this into my ***MainController***

```
@IBAction func didTapMenu(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    guard let menuViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuViewController") as? MenuViewController else { return }
    menuViewController.didTapMenuType = { menuType in
        self.transitionToNew(menuType)
    }
    menuViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    menuViewController.transitioningDelegate = self
    present(menuViewController, animated: true)
}
```

How can I add a ***SwipeGestureRecognizer*** to my transition? I appreciate every input. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you should instantiate viewController inside transition object. Your `ViewController` should have the transitions. And you can add gesture to `viewController`'s `view` and upon value change you will update the transition.

Comment: Do I have to add the gesture to my "MainViewController" where I add the SideMenu with its transition or in the "MenuController" where I declare the sections which I want to show?

Comment: If the `menuController` view is covering the full screen then you can keep it there otherwise you have to add it where you added this as child controller.

Comment: I updated my answer where I add the MenuViewController+